# Android activity restarts instead of resume

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest

Does anyone have any idea why an Android activity restarts itself instead of resume? There is no special functionality implemented in order to force the restart.

Thanks!

Comment: Because when activity launch it store in the stack. and when you click on device home button it goes resume state and then after recent to click open then it calls into the stack and open it.

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific? So, the scenario is as following: open activity1 -> open activity2 -> press back btn -> activity1 restarts instead of resume.

Comment: When open activity1  is stored in the stack and click on button open activity1  call second activity 2 is also stored in the stack and first activity resume. and when press back button the second activity remove from the stack then stack has only first activity call onResume method and it will be show it. Stack work LIFO manner.

Comment: This I understand. But why activity1 restarts itself. This is the normal behavior? Shouldn't it just resume?